# Rails: ruby code in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with a passing ruby code in javascript `script` tag

Now I have this code:

```
<script>
  var offer_foto = {
    slide_offer_preview_1: ['one.jpg', 'two.jpg', 'three.jpg'],
    slide_offer_preview_2: ['four.jpg', 'five.jpg', 'six.jpg']
  }
</script>
```

My Ruby code

```
<% for i in 0..@page[:proposals].count - 1 %>
  <%= @page[:proposals][i][:hotels][0]['hotel_images'].map{|f| f['url']} %>
<% end %>
```

In Javascript I need

```
slide_offer_preview_i: <%= @page[:proposals][i][:hotels][0]['hotel_images'].map{|f| f['url']} %>
```

Unfortunately I don't know how ti get it because I know Javascript not quite well. If you need more information please comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in the controller, not in the template. Keep logic far away from your templates.

In your controller:

```
@slide_offer_previews = []
for i in 0..@page[:proposals].count - 1
  @slide_offer_previews << @page[:proposals][i][:hotels][0]['hotel_images'].map{|f| f['url']}
end
```

Then in your view:

```
slide_offer_preview_i: <%= @slide_offer_previews[i] %>
```

---

Alternatively, if `@page[:proposals][i]` is an object, then add a method to your class:

```
def hotel_image_urls
  self[:hotels][0]['hotel_images'].map{|f| f['url']}
end
```

then in your view:

```
slide_offer_preview_i: <%= @page[:proposals][i].hotel_image_urls() %>
```

**edit**: Sorry, this doesn't even make syntactical sense. Disregard this alternate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Joe Frembach, you should do this in the controller. However, if you do need to embed Ruby into Javascript, you can do so by adding .erb (file_name.js.erb) to the file extension, in which case you can do something like:

```
alert('<%= @your_embedded_variable %>');
```

Comment: I'm okay with this as long as any minifiers are aware that this js is not cacheable. The js would need to be generated every page load, and is an extra request.